# Как в C# достать контент из кэша?

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте! Я новичок по c#, но хорошо знаю java.

Вопрос который сейчас я задаю должен быть очень лёгким:
как кэшировать и достать от кэша?

Например, когда обращаешься по какому-то адресу интернета сначала искать в кэше, если в кэше нету, то тогда достал этот контент из интернета и поставить в кэш

Если вы знаете C# и Java, внизу я привёл код на Java
На этот вопрос можно ответить и не зная Java.

Main.java

```java
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils; 

import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.InputStream; 
import java.net.*; 
import java.util.List; 
import java.util.Map; 

public class Main { 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 

        ResponseCache.setDefault(new ResponseCache() { 
            @Override 
            public CacheResponse get(URI uri, String rqstMethod,
                        Map<String, List<String>> rqstHeaders) throws IOException { 
                if (uri.toString().equals("http://google.com/")) { 
                    return new CacheResponse() { 
                        @Override 
                        public Map<String, List<String>> getHeaders() throws IOException { 
                            return null; 
                        } 

                        @Override 
                        public InputStream getBody() throws IOException { 
                            return null; 
                        } 
                    }; 
                } 
                return null; 
            } 

            @Override 
            public CacheRequest put(URI uri, URLConnection conn) throws IOException { 
                return null; 
            } 
        }); 

        URLConnection c = new URL("http://google.com/").openConnection(); 
        c.setUseCaches(true); 

        String html = IOUtils.toString(c.getInputStream()); 
        System.out.println(html); 

    } 
}
```

Приведите, пожалуйста, пример кода на С# по аналогии моего кода.

Comment: См. [Cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.caching.cache(v=vs.110).aspx) - используется в веб-приложениях, [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx) - используется в десктопных приложениях.

Comment: Уже радуюсь :/... Вы к кому именно обращаетесь? Указывайте @ник. Вот [адрес](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/), где ответят на большинство вопросов.

Answer (score 0):

Пусть `Response GetWebResponseFromUrl(string url)` - некоторый метод (который вы напишите самостоятельно) для получения Web-контента, тогда ответ на ваш вопрос выглядит примерно так:

```
Dictionary<string, Response> ResponseCache = new Dictionary<string, Response>();

Response GetWebResponse(string url)
{
    if (!ResponseCache.ContainsKey(url))
        ResponseCache[url] = GetWebResponseFromUrl(url);
    return ResponseCache[url];
}
```

Comment: Чуть-чуть не понял можете подробно привести пример